# Get return value in shell from external erlang file

Tags: shell, erlang

I have a script file in erlang that start some modules. In the erlang shell, I would like to use the returned objects from the start function.

I have my file :

```
-module(myfile).
main() ->
    %% do some operations
    MyReturnVar.
```

I want to have the easiest way for the final user to manipulate the `MyReturnVar` variable. In the shell script, I do `$ erl -s myfile main` which executes the function in the shell.

Is there a way to get the MyReturnVar in the shell ?

Another way is to load the module directly from the shell

```
$ erl
1> X = myfile:main().
```

but I don't like so much this solution, I'd like a more "one command" option (or several in a row I can do in a shell script).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you say several in a row, it sounds like you want to pipe the result of one command into another command. For that you don't use the return value, which can only be an int, but you use stdin and stdout. Meaning what you want is to print `MyReturnVar` to stdout. For that you have io:format. Depending on what type of value `MyReturnVar` is you would do something like this:

```
-module(myfile).
main() ->
    %% do some operations
    io:format("~w", [MyReturnVar]),
    MyReturnVar.
```

Now you should be able to pipe the result for your command to other processes. Ex:

```
$ erl -s myfile main | cat
```

Comment: No the idea is not to display the result in the terminal but to say to the user "just execute the script `run.sh` and then you will be in a erlang shell with the needed variables". I want to be able to execute other erlang operation with these variables. I just wanted to know it there is another way to do that than the `X = myfile:main()` operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could (ab)use the `.erlang` file to achieve this (see the `erl(1)` man page). Or hack around in [erlang-history](https://github.com/ferd/erlang-history)
.

Answer (score 0):

Use escript if possible.

```
$cat test.escript
#!/usr/local/bin/escript 
main([]) ->
        MyReturnVar=1,
        io:format("~w", [MyReturnVar]),
        halt(MyReturnVar).
$escript test.escript 
1
$echo $?
1
```

This will printout MyReturnVar and return MyReturnVar, so that you can use with pipe or just catch $? from shell script.